# Perl: while ($key = each %hash) doesn't stop at key = 0

Tags: perl, hash, each, while-loop

I don't need this, obviously; I'm just curious about what's going on here. Am I missing
something simple? Can I rely on this behaviour in all versions of Perl?)

Perl v5.8.8:

```
%h = ( 0=>'zero', 1=>'one', 2=>'two' );
while ($k = each %h) {
    $v = delete $h{$k};
    print "deleted $v; remaining: @h{0..2}\n";
}
```

outputs

```
deleted one; remaining: zero  two
deleted zero; remaining:   two
deleted two; remaining:
```

`man perlfunc` (each) does not explain why the
while loop continues when `$k` is assigned 0.
The code behaves as if the condition on the `while` loop
were `($k = each %h, defined $k)`.

If the loop condition is actually changed to
`($k = each %h, $k)` then it does indeed
stop at `$k = 0` as expected.

It also stops at `$k = 0` for the following
reimplementation of `each`:

```
%h = ( 0=>'zero', 1=>'one', 2=>'two' );
sub each2 {
    return each %{$_[0]};
}
while ($k = each2 \%h) {
    $v = delete $h{$k};
    print "deleted $v; remaining: @h{0..2}\n";
}
```

outputs just:

```
deleted one; remaining: zero  two
```

Answer (score 29):

You're calling `each` in scalar context, so it's not working because of a list return value.

Just like

```
while ($line = <FILE>)
```

is special-cased to add an implicit `defined`, so is

```
while ($key = each %hash)
```

In 5.8.8, that happens in op.c, lines 3760-3766:

```
case OP_SASSIGN:
  if (k1->op_type == OP_READDIR
      || k1->op_type == OP_GLOB
      || (k1->op_type == OP_NULL && k1->op_targ == OP_GLOB)
      || k1->op_type == OP_EACH)
    expr = newUNOP(OP_DEFINED, 0, expr);
  break;
```

I'm not sure if this applies to all versions of Perl 5.

See also: [When does while() test for defined vs truth](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=132451) on PerlMonks.  I can't find where this is mentioned in the Perl docs (the `<FILE>` case is mentioned, but I don't see the `each` case).

Answer (score 6):

cjm is right.  I just want to add that when coming up against strange things like this its often helpful to run your code through [B::Deparse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B::Deparse) to see how Perl understood your code.  I like to use the -p switch to show precedence mistakes, too.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,p your_example.plx
(%h) = (0, 'zero', 1, 'one', 2, 'two');
while (defined($k = each %h)) {
    $v = delete $h{$k};
    print "deleted $v; remaining: @h{0..2}\n";
}
your_example.plx syntax OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, cjm.
It was clear some kind of implicit addition of a `defined`
was going on like that for glob but not where it was 
documented. Now at least I know the limited cases in which
that special handling applies.

But the information should be in the perlfunc documentation,
not just the Perl source code!